# count nulls in Pandas dataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, null

I want to add a row to my pandas dataFrame that will state how many nulls each column has
i tried to use r=result.isna().sum().T.reset_index()
but for some reason it fail and or not doing it correctly
Thanks!

i tried to use pd.concat (df,df.isnull().sum().T)
i wanted to add the amount of nulls to the and of the dataframe
r=result.isna().sum().T.reset_index()

Answer (score 1):

If need new row use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
result.loc['sum nulls'] = result.isna().sum()
```

Or in your solution add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
out = pd.concat([result, result.isna().sum().to_frame('sum nulls').T])
```

If need new column use:

```
result['sum nulls'] = result.isna().sum(axis=1)

out = result.assign(**{'sum nulls': result.isna().sum(axis=1)})
```